# jQueryUI Autocomplete-Widget: I want to bind a function to the select event of the menu widget

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the following script using the jQueryUI autocomplete widget. It calls some function whenever a menu item in the selection box is being selected:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: [ "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp"],
            select: function() { 
                console.log("Element has been selected");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
```

This works nicely. But I need this method in a multiple of instances of the autocomplete widget, so I prefer extending the autocomplete widget using the [widget factory](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget-factory).

This works nicely whenever I want to override methods of the autocomplete plugin:

```js
$.widget("ui.myAutocomplete", $.extend({}, $.ui.autocomplete.prototype, {
    search: function( value, event ) {
        // this WORKS!
        console.log('overriding autocomplete.search')

        return $.ui.autocomplete.prototype.search.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}));
```

However, I have no clue how to do that for the underlying menu widget.

I tried to override the `_init` method and binding a function to the `select` event. However this does not work as I don't know how to access the `bind` method of the menu-widget (or this menu widget is not yet there at this point during runtime)

```js
$.widget("ui.myAutocomplete", $.extend({}, $.ui.autocomplete.prototype, {
    _init: function() {
        // this does NOT work. 
        this.bind('select', function() { console.log('item has been selected') })

        return $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}));
```

Comment: I'm a little confused--are you trying to define the same `select` event handler for all of your autocomplete widgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're close; you should be overriding `_create` instead of `_init`:

```
$.widget("ui.myAutocomplete", $.extend({}, $.ui.autocomplete.prototype, {
    _create: function() {
        // call autocomplete's default create method:
        $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._create.apply(this, arguments);

        // this.element is the element the widget was invoked with
        this.element.bind("autocompleteselect", this._select);
    },
    _select: function(event, ui) {
        // Code to be executed upon every select.
    }
}));
```

Usage:

```
$("input").myAutocomplete({
    /* snip */
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/EWsS4/

Comment: This would certainly work. However, I want this function to be encapsulated in an extension of the autocomplete widget. So I can call it via `$(".autocomplete").myAutocomplete()` whereas `myAutocomplete` is an extension of the `autocomplete` widget.

Comment: @Silvan: Okay--I'll adapt it to live inside of your widget.

Comment: @Silvan: After I got into creating a custom widget to wrap `autocomplete` it proved a little harder than I thought! Hope my answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot! (And as a nice side effect I now got to know jsfiddle :-)